# List Selector is not working in android

Tags: android, xml, android-listview, selector

I have List View in which I am setting alternate background color. Now I want to use list selector on list item click. 
This is the way I am setting alternate background using getView() of cursor adapter

> CursorAdapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    if (position % 2 == 0)
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#191919"));
    else
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#323232"));
    return row;

}
```

> list_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal" android:state_activated="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>
</selector>
```

> list_item_bg_pressed.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
</shape>
```

> list_item_bg_normal.xml

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle">
     <solid android:color="#00000000" /> <!-- transparent --> 
 </shape>
```

and finally I have my list view in which I have used listSelector.

> activity.xml

```
 <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:clickable="true"/>
```

I am unable to solve this. I don't know where I went wrong.
output of my screen is like this

[image]

Comment: What problem you face please specify.

Comment: listSelector is not working.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386035/custom-selector-for-list-background

Comment: I tried this also. It's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer. I have created two selector XML files to give alternate background. See this.

> selector_one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false"  android:drawable="@color/black1" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false"  android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
</selector>
```

> selector_two

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false"  android:drawable="@color/black2" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false"  android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
</selector>
```

and in the getView() method of adapter I have called both selectors.

```
if (position % 2 == 0) {
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_one);
 } else {
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_two);
 }
```

I took reference from this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552442/android-listview-alternate-row-color-but-with-default-cursor-selection)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try like this instead of drawable:

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="#00000000" android:state_activated="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="#FF0000" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="#FF0000" android:state_activated="true"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: no you cannot use color in drawable. see I got this error.  `Color types not allowed (at 'drawable' with value '#00000000').`